# Redirect to current page after wordpress login

Tags: redirect, login

I just want to redirect the users to their current page after logged in my wordpress website.
I have used the following but it won`t work for me since it is in page that created from the admin side.

```
<?php echo wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>
```

Comment: you can try using http_referer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001188/redirect-after-login-wordpress-urls,
http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/redirect-back-to-referring-page-after-login/

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`login_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) filter to do this. One of the parameters is `$request`, which

> is the URL the user is coming from

```
function wpse125952_redirect_to_request( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    // instead of using $redirect_to we're redirecting back to $request
    return $request;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'wpse125952_redirect_to_request', 10, 3);
```

The filter could additionally easily be used for distinguishing redirect destinations by user roles. Take a look at the documentation for a deeper insight into that.

Answer (score 1):

Try wp_redirect() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect
Maybe the_permalink() will help you depending on where you're logging in from.

Alternatively is this what you're looking for?

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by user's current page?

Anyway, have you tried using the built-in wp_login_form() function?

You may want to use it this way:

```
$args = array(
    'echo' => true,
    // This could be your User's Current Page?
    'redirect' => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ),
    'form_id' => 'user-login-form',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
    'id_username' => 'user_login',
    'id_password' => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
    'remember' => true,
    'value_username' => NULL,
    'value_remember' => false );

wp_login_form( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Below in your function.php

```
function admin_default_page() {
  $site=get_site_url();
  $site1=$site."/* slug- name for page*/";
  return $site1;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

Comment: Always include a bit of an explanation with your posted answer - that way users can get an understanding of what the solution is, why it's a good solution, what the different functionality is doing, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. I have installed a Wordpress plugin to execute Php code on pages.Then

```
<?php echo wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>
```

works well on wordpress pages.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/