# Redirect after login to current URL

Tags: functions, login, wp-login-form

I've my login box on any page of my WordPress and I'm trying to redirect to the same page after a user logs in.

For example:
If I make the login in the URL `http://localhost/wordpress/category/sub-category/sold`, redirect to the same URL.

I've this in my `functions.php` but, using my `$url` doesn't work.

How can make the redirection?

```
function login_go_home(){
    //$url ="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Are you using custom login form ?

Comment: Answered here no? :http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125952/redirect-to-current-page-after-wordpress-login

Comment: I used something like the link @mayersdesign but isn't works

Comment: No, I'm usign the Wordpress form @the_dramatist

Comment: Then how you are showing the login form in particular pages ? Otherwise you need to go to `wp-login.php` first then login. Please share your login form code by which your user getting logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I need to do the next step:

To redirect my logout, I put the next code in functions.php

```
function out_home(){        
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit();
}
add_action("wp_logout","out_home");
```

In my header.php, to change the value of my URL in the login:

```
$URL_POSTLOGIN = add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request);
    function login_go_home($URL_POSTLOGIN){         
        wp_redirect($URL_POSTLOGIN);
        exit();
    }
    add_action("wp_login","login_go_home");
```

Maybe is not the best solution but in my case others codes fails.